# reverse the numbers of an seperated array of arrays using .reverse() JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I want to reverse the numbers of the different arrays in "batch" and return it as new Array.

```
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];
```

This is my code so far:

```
const validateCred = cardID =>{
    let arr = cardID
    return arr.slice().reverse(arr.reverse())
}


console.log(validateCred(batch))
```

but it always reverse just the individual arrays, not the numbers inside.

Pls explain why yours will work and what's wrong with mine and if batch would be a nested array or not.

Thx <3

Comment: Can you give an example of what the expected output looks like?  It's not entirely clear from the question what you're intending to accomplish.

Comment: Edit: 

i just need the console log numbers from right to left inside the arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function would solve your issue.

```js
const validateCred = cardIDs => {
    return cardIDs.map(cardID => cardID.slice().reverse());
}
```

You are currently only reversing the `batch` array. Not the arrays inside of it.

Comment: how does the "(cardID => cardID.reverse()" part work? i Try to understand this

Comment: The reverse() method reverses an array in place. It returns the reference to the same array, the first array element becoming the last, and the last array element becoming the first. In other words, the elements' order in the array will be turned in the direction opposite to that previously stated. To learn more, check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: @stullex_ You should still call it as `cardID.slice().reverse()`. `reverse` is mutative

Comment: Functions don't usually modify their arguments *and* return their new values.

Comment: @Andrew, yap! fixing it.

Comment: @stullex_ The question is still missing the expected output and the actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong data type to the `validateCred` function.

Here you are passing an array of array of numbers to a function that expects an array of numbers:

```js
console.log(validateCred(batch))
```

To fix it, take that and feed it to `Array.map`:

```js
console.log(batch.map(cardID => validateCred(cardID)));
```

Snippet:

```js
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];

const validateCred = cardID => {
  let arr = cardID
  return arr.slice().reverse(arr.reverse())
}

console.log(batch.map(cardID => validateCred(cardID)));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? As I understand it, all you have to do is save the part inside `console.log` into a variable and you're good to go.